# Why winston is not logging http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I am trying to use winston library to log request and save it into a file.

```
logger.debug(req.body);
```

It saves [object Object] not the request body. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It's likely that `debug` is applying `toString()` to the object. Maybe try `JSON.stringify(req.body)`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you please answer this so i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can combine morgan with winston to log all requests automatically

```
var logger = new winston.Logger({
transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
        level: 'info',
        filename: './logs/all-logs.log',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false
    })
],
   exitOnError: false
}),

logger.stream = {
    write: function(message, encoding){
        logger.info(message);
    }
};

app.use(require("morgan")("combined", { "stream": logger.stream }));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this

```
logger.debug(req.body.toSource());
```

The toSource() method represents the source code of an object.